# How to do SELECT COUNT(*) GROUP BY of ForeignKey field in Django?

Tags: python, django

Let's say we have three models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Platform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')

class SellingItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='selling_items')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

The idea here is to get a **total** of the different **categories** and **platforms** based on a **SellingItem**'s queryset.

My initial approach is:

```
categories = queryset.values('product__category__id', 'product__category__name', 'product__category__label').annotate(total=Count('product__category__id'))  # noqa: E501
platforms = queryset.exclude(product__platform__isnull=True).values('product__platform__id', 'product__platform__name', 'product__platform__label').annotate(total=Count('product__platform__id'))  # noqa: E501
```

The problem is that the result is not grouped...

The code is working on based on a **Product**'s queryset if removing all *product__* in the previous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach towards the problem is absolutely correct. Although you are missing a small thing at the end which is '.order_by()'. If you add it, you should get your desired result. What this does is that it will tell django to not apply **any** type of ordering. Thus, you will achieve your result.

This issue occurred because django tried to apply default ordering it has thus your queryset didn't output the desired results.

```
categories = queryset.values('product__category__id', 'product__category__name', 'product__category__label').annotate(total=Count('product__category__id')).order_by()  # order_by at the end.
platforms = queryset.exclude(product__platform__isnull=True).values('product__platform__id', 'product__platform__name', 'product__platform__label').annotate(total=Count('product__platform__id')).order_by()  # order_by at the end.
```